# Loopback $owner doesn't works for findById

Tags: node.js, acl, relation, loopback, apiconnect

I would like to get some informations about my user with loopback.
For that I created a `"user"` model related with `"accessToken"` model until now a POST on `/user`, a POST on `/user/login` and a POST on `/user/logout` is working.

I added on `/common/models/user.json`

```
{
  "name": "user",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "accessTokens": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "accessToken",
      "foreignKey": "userId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "logout"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "findById"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

And when I do a GET on `/user/{id}` I got :

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 401,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "Autorisation requise",
    "code": "AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED",
    "stack": "Error: Autorisation requise\n    at..."
  }
}
```

I guess I didn't understand acl/relation very well

Comment: Can you check your `model-config.json` to make sure, that the built-in `User` model isn't public? It's possible that you are routing to it instead of your custom user model. Also `findById` maps to `READ accessType`

Comment: can u please change  "accessType": "EXECUTE"  to  "accessType": "*" and than check.

Comment: Do you have token authorization enabled in your loopback application? If yes, you should provide access token with your `/user/{id}` request.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you are only allowing `$owner` to `findById`:

> To qualify a $owner, the target model needs to have a belongsTo relation to the User model (or a model that extends User) and property matching the foreign key of the target model instance.  The check for $owner is performed only for a remote method that has ‘:id’ on the path, for example, GET /api/users/:id.

1. Make sure the `accessToken` you are providing is the owner of the `id` of the `user` you are looking for.
2. If you are not sure, try to replace:
   `"principalId": "$owner"` with `"principalId": "$authenticated"`, then you'll know if that's your problem.